# Unix command to print the first sentence

Tags: linux, unix

Given a text file (textfile.txt), such as:

```
Hello there. I have the high ground.
```

How would I print just the first sentence so that it's just:

```
Hello there.
```

Answer (score 1):

use awk or cut like this

```
cat textfile.txt | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

or

```
cat textfile.txt | cut -d'.' -f1
```

Comment: Why do you feel the urge to use `cat`?